# Xcode install command via OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, xcode

I have `Mac OS X` version `10.5.7` so I downloaded `Xcode` version `4.6.3` and launched it.

According to many tutorials (such as [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/)) I am supposed to install further command line tools via terminal: `xcode-select --install`

But all I get is a little manual page:

```
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

I went into the `Applications` directory and tried to run the command from there, but the same outcome.

In fact, the content of my `Applications` directory revealed through the following command is strange:

```
~ cd Applications

~ ls
Chrome Apps.localized
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: When you `cd Applications`, you're really going into `/Users/(your username)/Applications`. You need to use `cd /Applications`

Answer (score 2):

The command line install works on much newer OS than yours - the tutorial you link is 10.10 and Xcode 6 or 7.

If you can't upgrade to 10.6.8 and then get past Lion, I would suggest run the graphical installer and look for Xcode possibly in `/Developer` if you don't see it in the `/Applications` folder.

Comment: Thank you. In the graphical installer, under `Preferences` and then `Downloads`, I selected to install the `Command Line Tools` but I get this message that stops the installation: `The package "BluetoothSDK.pkg" is untrusted.` Have you come across this before? How do I proceed?

Comment: @Joshua It could be as simple as the certificate used to sign that bundle has expired. Are you able to inspect the certificate or try setting the clock back 2 years and re-trying?